# Using group by in subquery in JPA Specification

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

There are two models: `Event` & `Session`, which has one-to-many relationship.

I want to create a predicate using JPA Criteria API based on a SQL like this:

```
SELECT event.* FROM events JOIN (
    SELECT event.id, MIN(session.start) AS start FROM 
        events JOIN sessions ON events.id = sessions.event_id 
        GROUP BY event.id
    ) TMP on events.id = TMP.id 
    WHERE start >= '2018-08-01 00:00:00';
```

I refer this link: http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/04/28/criteria-group-clause/ to build the group by subquery.

But I stuck due to `SubQuery` doesn't have `multiselect` function, how to build a predicate based on a group by subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try a query as follows, with and `in` condition of aggregated dates with `min` function and `having` clause

```
select event from Event event 
and event.session.start in 
    (select min(nestedEvent.session.start) minDates
        FROM Event nestedEvent
    group by nestedEvent.id
    having minDates >= '2018-08-01 00:00:00')
```